# Memory saving alternatives to Counter tuple keys splitting

Tags: python, memory-management, tuples, hashtable, counter

The input is a list of string tuples and I need a count of

- how many times each string tuple occurs
- how many times one element of the string tuple occurs
- how many times the other element of the string tuple occurs

I am currently doing it as such:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = [('foo','bar'), ('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'doo'), ('joo', 'doo'), ('koo', 'lar')]
>>> datacount = Counter(data)
>>> datacount
Counter({('foo', 'bar'): 2, ('joo', 'doo'): 1, ('koo', 'lar'): 1, ('foo', 'doo'): 1})
>>> x, y = zip(*datacount.keys())
>>> x
('joo', 'foo', 'koo', 'foo')
>>> y
('doo', 'bar', 'lar', 'doo')
>>> xcount = Counter(x)
>>> ycount = Counter(y)
>>> xcount
Counter({'foo': 2, 'koo': 1, 'joo': 1})
>>> ycount
Counter({'doo': 2, 'bar': 1, 'lar': 1})
```

But I realize it takes up three separate Counters. **Is there an alternative to getting the counts and other data structure that I can fetch the counts easily?**

Comment: whats inefficient about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep precomputed counts for X,Y, and X*Y then there's no way around keeping a value for each possible X,Y, and X*Y and your current solution is as good as any.

If it's the fact that you're using 3 separate `Counter` objects that bothers you, you could keep all counts in a single `Counter`, although it won't reduce memory usage.

If having everything precomputed and loaded in memory is not a requirement, you can:

- **Keep 'pointers' instead of objects** - If the actual strings are very large and you want to avoid loading them into memory, you could assign an id to each, keep a counts for ids and only map back to strings when necessary.
- **Lazy loading/counting** - you could maintain a mapping of each string to the tuples it appears in on disk, and compute counts on demands by only loading the relevant tuples, i.e.:

.

```
def count(x,y):
    X = load_tuples(x)
    Y = load_tuples(y)
    XY = [t for t in X if t[1] == y]
    return map(len,[X,Y,XY])
```